# How to use google documentviewer on website.(using a googleId url that points to a non public file)

Tags: google-drive-api

**I'm wondering how to view files using a url like this:**

```
  https://docs.google.com/a/myDomain/viewer
```

Ive been trying with this:

```
  http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fa%2FmyDomain%2Ffile%2Fd%2FgoogleId%2F
```

But I keep getting the viewer with some weird html in it.

**Is there any way to make this kind of url using the id or the API?**

How can I view a certain file using this kind of url. I also don't wan't to make it public.

I've been using webContentLinks but that requires the pdf to be downloaded by adobe reader or another plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve it as an editable doc, use `alternateLink`. If you just want to embed a read-only version of the doc `embedLink` is what you are looking for.

Both of the properties are available on `drive#file` type.

Comment: When I use the viewer link in combination with the alternateLink I seem to get a google viewer with a html file. I want to use the google viewer since sending an embedded document takes too long.

Comment: embedLink is always empty when I call it from the api.